# How to switch column dates into rows in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, calendar

I have an Excel where there are people listed in rows and the working dates in columns. Each day is a cell (col)

**Data:**

```
Employee    January
        01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 
-------------------------------------
Joe      1  1  1  1           1  1  1
John     1  1  1
```

I want the following result

**Expected output:**

```
Employee    Work On Date   Work Off date
----------------------------------------
Joe         2019-01-01     2019-01-04
Joe         2019-01-08     2019-01-10
John        2019-01-01     2019-01-03
```

I can't find a way just by doing it manually.

I was thinking to insert into a database everything and then work from there... but my problem is to bulk all data as the expected result. Is there a way to achieve that with Excel or Excel/SQL?

Answer (score 0):

I try to create a piece of code to satisfy your needs:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long, LastRowNew As Long, Row As Long, Column As Long
    Dim StartingDate As String, EndingDate As String, Name As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("A" & LastRow + 2).Value = "Employee"
        .Range("B" & LastRow + 2).Value = "Work On Date"
        .Range("C" & LastRow + 2).Value = "Work Off Date"

        For Row = 3 To LastRow

            LastColumn = .Cells(Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            Name = Range("A" & Row).Value
            StartingDate = ""

            For Column = 2 To LastColumn

                If .Cells(Row, Column).Value <> "" And StartingDate = "" Then
                    StartingDate = "2018-" & .Cells(1, Column).Value & "-" & .Cells(2, Column).Value
                    LastRowNew = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                    .Range("A" & LastRowNew + 1).Value = Name
                    .Range("B" & LastRowNew + 1).Value = CDate(StartingDate)
                ElseIf .Cells(Row, Column).Offset(0, 1).Value = "" And StartingDate <> "" Then
                    EndingDate = "2018-" & .Cells(1, Column).Value & "-" & .Cells(2, Column).Value
                    .Range("C" & LastRowNew + 1).Value = CDate(EndingDate)
                    StartingDate = ""
                End If

            Next Column

        Next Row

    End With

End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it by formula using offset ranges:

In (say) A12

```
=IFERROR(IF(ROW()=12,A3,IF(COUNTIF(A$11:A11,A11)<COUNTIFS(INDEX($B$3:$K$4,MATCH(A11,A$3:A$4,0),0),1,INDEX($A$3:$J$4,MATCH(A11,A$3:A$4,0),0),"<>1"),
A11,INDEX(A$3:A$4,MATCH(A11,A$3:A$4,0)+1))),"")
```

In B12

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(A:J)/((INDEX(A$3:J$4,MATCH(A12,A$3:A$4,0),0)<>1)*(INDEX(B$3:K$4,MATCH(A12,A$3:A$4,0),0)=1)),COUNTIF(A$11:A12,A12))
```

and in C12

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(A:J)/((INDEX(B$3:K$4,MATCH(A12,A$3:A$4,0),0)=1)*(INDEX(C$3:L$4,MATCH(A12,A$3:A$4,0),0)<>1)),COUNTIF(A$11:A12,A12))
```

[image]

This just produces a day number at present and you can add December 31st to get a date.